# The number of search results is wrong for unregistered users

Tags: bug, search, users

It looks like for some reason the number of search results for unregistered users is completely misleading (always shows **500**).

### Unregistered users

[image: Search results for unregistered users]

### Registered users

[image: Search results for logged in user]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug. Non registered users have rate limits on how often they can use the search and I believe that also may well include a hard limit on the number of results that are shown when using non-tag searches... so searching for `[highcharts]` will work the same for both registered/non-registered, but text searching is limited...

Comment: Interesting point. I wonder though if it could not be presented better, as for me it seems like a UX issue (if not a bug). After all the end user is just given an information that on StackOverflow there are just 500 questions for such term (which is much less impressive than 44500), it is simply misleading as well.

Comment: The number of pages of results is consistent though (so there's 10 pages available when selecting 50 results per page)... I think it's mostly there to deter/hinder scrapers from being able to scrape for arbitrary terms from search itself. That being the case, it'd perhaps be even more misleading to show there's 44,557 results when you can only specify a maximum page of 10 (attempting to do anything greater than that - triggers a captcha and puts you back to page 10 anyway)...

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes this ticket "works as designed" (although I still have no idea how a new user is supposed to understand/know that his search results were limited). Thanks for the explanation!